# highlight div or p after loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Hello i need to highlight a div after my page is loading, i don't know if i should use a partial or something like that, the partial also has to have 2 variables disponible.

Code to highlight after loading by 5 seconds:

```
<div id="total_de_venta">
<% if @instalador.a_destajo? %>
<div align="right"><b>Total de la venta: $<%= @venta.precio_de_venta + @venta.precio_de_instalacion*2 %></b></div>

<% else %>
<div align="right"><b>Total de la venta: $<%= @venta.precio_de_venta + @venta.precio_de_instalacion*2 %></b></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

controller :

```
def show


  @venta = Venta.find(params[:id])

  @este_instalador_id = @venta.instalador_id



  @instalador = Instalador.find_by_id(@este_instalador_id)


  #visual_effect(:highlight, "total_zone", :duration => 3.0)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @project }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do it by some Javascript only construction? I'm not a ruby programmer, but I'm sure you can add a 'onLoad' event to your page. The 'onLoad' event fires after the page is loaded. In the 'onLoad' handler you can add your desired effect, e.g. :

```
Effect.Highlight($('id_of_element'), [ your options]);
```

To add more than one 'onLoad' handler and execute them all, you can use the following Prototype function:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', yourJavascriptFunction);
```